# Typerror on python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

Im getting an `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`  while running this code. The thing is that it works fine on python 3.5.2 (conda) but it gives this error when on python 3.6.1 (conda).

Anyone has idea how to change it to make it work on both versions? Or at least the newer one?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math 

def geneticAlgorithm(f, x_min, x_max, cel, popSize, pMut, maxIter):


  result = {
        'x_opt': None,
        'f_opt': None,
        'x_hist': [],
        'f_hist': [],
        'f_mean': []

  }

  # Check the number of dimensions
  Dim = len(x_min) 

  # Initialize Population

  population = np.full((popSize, cel*Dim), None)
  for i in range(popSize):
    population[i,:] = np.random.uniform(cel*Dim)<0

  coordinates = getCoordinates(population, cel, x_min, x_max, pMut)

  # Calculate fittness of individuals
  objFunction = [None]*popSize
  for i in range(popSize):
    objFunction[i] = f(coordinates[i,:])


  # Assign the first population to output 
  result['x_opt'] = coordinates[np.argmin(objFunction),]
  result['f_opt'] = f(coordinates[np.argmin(objFunction),])

  # The generational loop
  finished = False
  currIter = 1
  while(finished == False):
    # Assign the output
    if currIter <= maxIter:
      if result['f_opt'] > f(coordinates[np.argmin(objFunction),]):
        result['x_opt']= coordinates[np.argmin(objFunction),]
        result['f_opt']= f(coordinates[np.argmin(objFunction),])

      result['f_hist'].append(result['f_opt'])

      result['x_hist'].append(coordinates[np.argmin(objFunction)])
      result['f_mean'].append(np.mean(objFunction))
    else: finished = True


    # Translate binary coding into real values  
    coordinates = getCoordinates(population, cel, x_min, x_max, pMut)

    # Calculate fittness of the individuals
    objFunction = [None]*popSize
    for i in range(popSize):
        objFunction[i] = f(coordinates[i,:])


    rFitt = min(objFunction)/objFunction # Relative Fittness
    nrFitt = rFitt / sum(rFitt) # Relative Normalized (sum up to 1) Fittness
    # Selection operator (Roulette wheel)
    selectedPool = [0] * popSize

    for i in range(popSize):
      selectedPool[i] = sum(np.random.uniform()>np.cumsum(nrFitt))+1 #znowu runif i cumsum


    # Crossover operator (for selected pool)
    nextGeneration = np.full((popSize, cel*Dim), None)
    for i in range(1, popSize):
      parentId = np.round(random.uniform(1,popSize))
      cutId = np.round(random.uniform(1,Dim*cel-1)) # Please, do not exceed the matrix sizes

      nextGeneration[i, 0:int(cutId)] = population[selectedPool[i]-1, 0:int(cutId)]
      nextGeneration[i, (cutId): (Dim*cel)] = population[selectedPool[int(parentId)-1]-1, (cutId) : (Dim*cel)]


    # Mutation operator
    for i in range(popSize):
      arr=np.arange(Dim*cel)
      test1=np.random.uniform(size=Dim*cel)>pMut
      genomeMutId = arr[np.where(test1)] # Draw the genomes that will mutate
      for j in range(len(genomeMutId)):
        nextGeneration[i, genomeMutId[j]] = not(nextGeneration[i, genomeMutId[j]]) 



    # Replace the old population
    population = nextGeneration
    currIter = currIter + 1

  return(result)


def intbin(x):
  #   # Translate the binary coding to real values numbers
  b = [2**(idx+1) for idx, v in enumerate(x) if v]
  return sum(b) 

def getCoordinates(population, cel, x_min, x_max, pMut):
  # Transform the binary coding into coordinates
  coordinates = np.full((population.shape[0], 2), 0)

  for i in range(population.shape[0]):
    for j in range(2):

      s1=cel*(j)+1
      s2=(j+1)*cel

      coordinatesTemp = intbin(population[i, range(s1,s2)])

      coordinates[i,j] = ((x_max[j]-x_min[j])/(2**cel-1))*coordinatesTemp+x_min[j]

  return(coordinates)




xSeed  = (3, 4)
n_grid  = 100
ub_iter = 100

def myFun(x) :
    return ( 0.6 + ((math.sin(x[0]**2-x[1]**2))**2-0.5)/((1+0.001*(x[0]**2+x[1]**2))**2) )

ga = geneticAlgorithm(myFun, (-20, -20), (20, 20), cel=50, popSize = 30, maxIter = ub_iter, pMut = 0.05)

print(ga)
```

So I ran this code using jupyter with python 3.6.1 and it doesnt work. It works fin on c9.io (that is python 3) and my older version of 3.5.2 on jupyter on another PC. It seems that the problem here is with the lines here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-71595b494779> in <module>()
    167     return ( 0.6 + ((math.sin(x[0]**2-x[1]**2))**2-0.5)/((1+0.001*(x[0]**2+x[1]**2))**2) )
    168 
--> 169 ga = geneticAlgorithm(myFun, (-20, -20), (20, 20), cel=50, popSize = 30, maxIter = ub_iter, pMut = 0.05)
    170 
    171 print(ga)

<ipython-input-1-71595b494779> in geneticAlgorithm(f, x_min, x_max, cel, popSize, pMut, maxIter)
    108       #print(selectedPool[int(parentId)-1])
    109       nextGeneration[i, 0:int(cutId)] = population[selectedPool[i]-1, 0:int(cutId)]
--> 110       nextGeneration[i, (cutId): (Dim*cel)] = population[selectedPool[int(parentId)-1]-1, (cutId) : (Dim*cel)]
    111 
    112 

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: How about posting a full stack trace?

Comment: I ran it in Jupyter with python 3.6.0 and numpy version 1.11.3 and, apart from a bunch of DepreciationWarnings, it ran fine.

Comment: its included now

Comment: Have you tried to [catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print the relevant data? - what did you find?

Comment: I think a big problem with what you are doing is trying to do too much on one line. It's not bad practice to use more variables and split thing up.
`nextGeneration[i, (cutId): (Dim*cel)] = population[selectedPool[int(parentId)-1]-1, (cutId) : (Dim*cel)]`

This is a horrible line of python. Put each index into it's own variable and see where the error occurs. I have a strong suspicion it's due to accidentally using tuples in your indexing.

Comment: use `print(..)` and `print(type(..))` to check your variables before `nextGeneration` (line 110). It seems one of them is incorrect or has wrong type.

Comment: Did something change between python versions? They are of correct types and it seem to work. I suspect it is cutId which a float, thus cant be used to slice that matrix. However on older python version its slicing without problem and gives a correct result. When I change cutId to integer then it runs on the newer python but the result is wrong.

Comment: Which version of numpy are you on? `print(np.__version__)`

Comment: BTW: why in one line you use `int(cutId)` but in next (with problem) only `(cutId)`

Comment: Using 1.12.1 numpy

Comment: I can't reproduce the "result is wrong" effect.  When I add `cutId = int(cutId)`,  to handle the fact that slicing became stricter, and set the random seeds for both Python and numpy so that the same random numbers will be generated in both runs, I get the same results in both versions.

Comment: Are you sure they are the same? Using int i get whole number while float in the arrays give me them with many digits so they are a bit different (small differences but still)

Comment: Yes: comparing the output gives me differences of `x_hist 0
f_opt 0.0
f_mean 0.0
x_opt 0
f_hist 0.0`.